# UIScrollView carousel menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to figure out if I can get what I want out of UIScrollView through some trickery or whether I need to roll my own scroll view

I have a series of items in row that I want to scroll through. One item should always be centered in the view, but other items should be visible to either side. In other words, I want normal scrolling and edge bouncing, but I want the deceleration when the user ends a touch to naturally settle at some specified stop point. (Actually now that I think of it, this behavior is similar to coverflow in this respect.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this project: [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel, it's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the "pageingEnabled" property of a UIScrollView. Basically you can define a size of a segment and the number of segments. Then it will automatically stop to adjust to that specific segment like you want. If you set the segments to be smaller than the actual width of the screen I think you should get the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: Note that this feature of paging was only added in iOS5. Prior to that the paging only works in whole-view-sized increments.